# Custom Login page retrieve null data C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have Login page which Customer should login with their Email adresse ,But when i write email adresse and hit button , its just redirected me to the same page i was before (Login) and than i debugge the code and its retrieve all null.Can anyone direct me in the right direction? thx

Comment: Any other code in the view?  Why is `cust` always coming to the controller with no data?

Comment: So the specific problem is that `cust` has `null` values?  Where *should* it be getting values?  What is being posted to that controller action?

Comment: @StephenWilson , No there is no more code & to be honest I dont why Cust coming with no data . if you can suggest something to find out why cust coming with no data :-)

Comment: @David it seems and should getting data from db from Customer Table

Comment: @ManDown: You seem to be misunderstanding quite a few things in this code.  The `user` variable is an attempt to get data from the database.  The `cust` variable is being passed to the method itself.  Your debugging screen shot appears to be examining the `cust` variable.  Perhaps you've made a mistake?

Comment: @David i just debugging again and user also null and it colud be i made mistake , is there anything i can do to fix the issue ?! and just quick question why cust & user both are null !!

Comment: @ManDown: Well, `user` is likely `null` as a side-effect of `cust` having `null` values, and thereby not matching any records in the data.  What you need to determine is where `cust` *should* be getting its values.  Where is the form that posts to this controller action?  What information is included in that form post?  If no values are supplied to the action then of course it wouldn't have any values to put in the `cust` object.

Comment: @David - i just added form login to my question & i was try putting Email in Cust variable  to tell my code Email = Email or it could be wrong ! all i wanna try to do is , customers login with their email adresse and in another way check if Email match to that Email adrsses in DB if is it match customer can login

Comment: @ManDown: It looks like the *only* input in that form is the email address.  If that's the case then you don't really need the model at all, your action method can just have a `string email` parameter.  It's also worth noting that a login which has *only* a username and *no* password is terribly insecure.

Comment: @David - i just changed to this var user = db.Customer.Where(u => u.E_Mail == u.E_Mail).FirstOrDefault(); and its works ,BUT no matter wat email i used to login .. it will be login anyway .. how can i fix this or how can i tell to my query every email have Customer id if this to matched so user can login

Comment: @ManDown: Well, of course that will always return a record.  When would the condition `u.E_Mail == u.E_Mail` ever *not* be true?  Focus on addressing the root of the problem, don't just randomly change things and hope for the best.

Comment: @David Im focus on problem and im not dat type to change things randomly i know wat i want , but my problem always is how to put things togethar and for this case i should include UserID into my query or they gonna figure out by themselves !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your debugging screen shot, your `ED_data_A_S_Customer` model has a property called `E_Mail`.  But the form element you're using is named `Email`.  These names are different.  As a result, the ASP.NET MVC Framework's model binder has no way to know where to get the `E_Mail` value.

Change your form element to match your model:

```
<input style="color:black;" id="Email" name="E_Mail" value="" required="" type="email" placeholder="Kunde ID ..." class="input">
                                       <!--  ^here  -->
```

Since you're only using a single value, you could also just as easily not use the model at all and just use that single value:

```
public ActionResult Login(string e_mail)
```

(Name it whatever you like, just make sure the form element's name matches.)

Of course, it's also worth noting here that a login which has *only* a username and *no* password is terribly insecure.

Comment: Thx David for help and your Time , but i dont wanna just move on with out Understanding Problem , as professional.. if you dont mind ,can you just tell where was my problem , beacuse i always have problem with kind of staff and i wanna learn and fix this issue when i coding

Comment: @ManDown: The problem was exactly where this answer indicated.  Your form and your model didn’t match.  So effectively the form wasn’t supplying the value you were looking for in the server side code.